# Let a CSS grid item begin inside its container and stretch it across the container's boundary exactly to browsers right edge

Tags: javascript, html, css-grid

In my last three projects three different screen designers confronted me with the same kind of problem. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

I have a fluid content grid container with a maximum width of let's say 800px. If the viewport is larger than 800px, the grid container is centered within the browser window. One element is expected to start inside the grid container (let's say in column 3) and to stretch across the container's boundary all the way to the right browser edge. To prevent me sneaking around the problem by setting a fixed row height and just position my element absolutely with something like "right: -999999px;" and put an "overflow: hidden;" on the body, the element in question has a dynamic height and must define the height of its grid row - let's say, an image with a fixed aspect ratio lives here.

As you can see, the image above is a browser screenshot - I already figured out a solution. The problem: It's far from elegant, and it requires 11 lines of JS. Let me show you:

```js
function getScrollbarWidth() {
  return window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth + "px";
}



function setScrollbarWidth() {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
    '--scrollbarWidth',
    getScrollbarWidth()
  );
}


setScrollbarWidth();
window.onresize = setScrollbarWidth;
```

```css
:root {
  --contentMaxWidth: 800px;
  --outsideGrid: max(0%, calc(100vw - var(--contentMaxWidth)));
  --stretch: calc((var(--outsideGrid) / 2) - (var(--scrollbarWidth) / 2));
}



body {
  margin: 0;
}



.grid {
  margin: 50px auto;
  max-width: var(--contentMaxWidth);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}



.grid__item {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  height: 150px;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: darkslategrey;
}



.grid__item--stretched {
  grid-column: 3/-1;
  margin-inline-end: calc(var(--stretch) * -1);
  height: auto;
  aspect-ratio: 3/1;
  background-color: firebrick;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__item grid__item--top">
      I'm inside the grid
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item grid__item--stretched">
      I start inside the grid, but end exactly at the browser's edge
    </div>
    <div class="grid__item grid__item--bottom">
      I'm inside the grid
    </div>
  </div>
```

Short explanation:

In my first version I let CSS calculated the space outside the grid container (if there is any space), divided that by two (space left/right) and attached the result as a negative right margin to the now stretched element.

The problem: this only works as long as there is no vertical scrollbar, since the scrollbar width is not taken into account. To achieve this, I have to a) check if there is a scrollbar at all and b) what width it has - different browsers have different scollbar widths. And yes, I could set the scrollbar width myself and hard code that value - but that's for the designer to decide, and I would much prefer maintainable code without magic numbers.

So I additionally need some JS to get the scrollbar width and communicate it to my CSS, which then can take the scrollbar width into account.

My solution works, but all the time I feel I might have a blind spot and I am missing something very obvious to everybody but me.

Is there a simpler way to achieve the same result? Preferably without the use of JS?